# Import ovf and/or vmdk to Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v

I have an OVF and a VMDK file. It was exported from VMWare.
How can I import that into a Hyper-V?
I do not have access to the VMWare server.
I don't have System Center - just Hyper-V Manager.
Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a VMDK to VHD](http://superuser.com/questions/483756/converting-a-vmdk-to-vhd)

Answer (score 1):

download

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42497

import module using powershell

Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter\MvmcCmdlet.psd1"

convert

ConvertTo-MvmcVirtualHardDisk -SourceLiteralPath      C:\mypath\mydisk.vmdk -VhdFormat vhd -DestinationLiteralPath C:\mynewdisk.vhd

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the OVF exported from VMware into a Hyper V host by using the Microsoft standalone software called Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter . You can download the OVF and convert it into Hyper V config folder which can be imported back into Hyper V.
For further details, check this link :
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn873998.aspx

Comment: Don't you need a server for that tool to work?

Comment: There's no instructions on the given link about importing or converting an ovf to hyper-v

Comment: I tried it, and indeed you have to have a VMWare server, with IP address and login; it doesn't seem to work directly via the GUI. However, per the answer by Fabio, you can use some of the tools the MVMC installs. Finding the download is hard, however. Probably easier to use the Oracle VirtualBox software.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly newer answer (come on Microsoft, if you believe in open source, build a converter into Hyper-V) would be to use the Oracle Virtual box software.

Virtual Box Manager or vboxmanage is a command line utility that comes with VirtualBox, which is a hypervisor supported by Oracle. Oracle's downloads are a bit clunky but VirtualBox has it's own site: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

First, install VirtualBox. This installs `vboxmanage`, which is a multiplatform utility for Windows, Linux, and macOS. The vboxmanage utility can do more operations than the graphical user interface of VirtualBox and can convert virtual disks of different formats.

Open a CLI and CD to the directory where VirtualBox is installed (we use the default installation path in this example), and run the command to convert a VMDK virtual disk to a VHD format for Hyper-V, or run directly:

```
    "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" clonehd --format vhd "C:\TEMP\whatever.vmdk" "C:\TEMP\whatever.vhd"
```

Note that older instructions may say `c:\program files (x86)`

Once you've converted the disk, you can create a new VM (honestly, not much to that), and attach the newly converted disk to it, instead of installing from virtual CD/ISO or network.

The Oracle utility only creates VHD's, so you may want to convert to VHDX.

By the way - Oracle says not to run Hyper-V at the same time, but I didn't have any problems. I didn't do any benchmarks though. I did have an issue connecting to WiFi, for some reason both VirtualBox and VMWare showed odd networking connectors that had very different names from the O/S and Hyper-V network connections. I was able to get Ethernet to work, but oddly not WiFi. I just like Hyper-V's machine connection methods and networking  much better, so I converted some Oracle demo VM's over to Hyper-V. It did seem to be a little faster, and much easier networking.