# Convert OVA to VHD for usage in Hyper-V

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I have a OVA file that I need to convert to VHD in order to use Hyper-V. Opening the `.ova` file in winrar gives me one `.ovf` file and one `.vmdk` file. I tested the program `Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter 3.0` that was recommended on SU but it required a host server. I do not have that, I only have the file.

[Import ovf and/or vmdk to Hyper-V](https://superuser.com/questions/820426/import-ovf-and-or-vmdk-to-hyper-v)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Quite easy actually, install VirtualBox that comes with the program VBoxManage.exe. It can be used with `clonehd` to specify the new format of the disk. You specify the original disk file, in this case the .vmdk, and then give a location and name to output the .vhd.

Open a cmd prompt, CD to `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox` or Virtualbox install directory and then run:

```
VBoxManage.exe clonehd --format vhd "C:\temp\VM\disk1.vmdk" "C:\temp\VM\disk1.vhd"
```

Documentation for VirtualBox:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevdi

Then I created a new virtual machine from `Hyper-V Manager` and selected "Use an existing virtual hard disk". Worked perfectly.

Use this guide for internet access:

https://superuser.com/a/472854/405096

Answer (score 6):

I can't comment yet, but this is a followup to the comment of **Ogglas**

If you get the message:

> 'VBoxManage.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Try to enter the entire path of VBOXManage.exe in my case, that would be:

> B:\Virtualbox\VBoxManage.exe

The new command would then be:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" clonehd --format vhd "C:\temp\VM\disk1.vmdk" "C:\temp\VM\disk1.vhd"
```

Source:
https://serverfault.com/questions/365423/how-to-run-vboxmanage-exe

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble getting VirtualBox to do this correctly for me. Instead, I used an official Microsoft Tool. You can download the Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42497

An example of what I did to get this working for me:

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter\mvmcCmdlet.psd1"

ConvertTo-MvmcVirtualHardDisk -SourceLiteralPath C:\Temp\myvm.vmdk -VhdType DynamicHardDisk -VhdFormat Vhdx -DestinationLiteralPath C:\Temp\myvm
```

Comment: "this tool is no longer available" at that link. I found announcement of it being retired: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/system-center-blog/microsoft-virtual-machine-converter-mvmc-is-being-retired/ba-p/351541.

Comment: aha! [tag:chocolatey] has the last published version: https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/virtualmachineconverter