# Migrating a Linux (CentOS) .ova to a Windows Hyper-V

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, hyper-v, cross-platform

I tried following the steps outlined here: [Convert OVA to VHD for usage in Hyper-V](https://superuser.com/questions/1133256/convert-ova-to-vhd-for-usage-in-hyper-v)

But when I try to load the vhd into Hyper-V in Windows it's telling me it's corrupted, I'm suspecting it's because the cloned media is for a Linux Kernal.

Is there a process for migrating a Linux Kernal from virtualbox to hyper-V on windows?

I tried converting it using Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter with not luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481737/error-when-converting-vmware-virtual-disk-to-hyperv, I'm getting error `ConvertTo-MvmcVirtualHardDisk : The entry 88888888-95df-4fde-86ce-ed1390fc6f0a is not a supported disk database entry for the descriptor.` This is the descriptor of the VMDK file:

```
# Disk DescriptorFile
version=1
CID=f00f4f2a
parentCID=ffffffff
createType="monolithicSparse"

# Extent description
RW 4294965248 SPARSE "disk123.vmdk"

# The disk Data Base 
#DDB

ddb.virtualHWVersion = "4"
ddb.adapterType="ide"
ddb.geometry.cylinders="16383"
ddb.geometry.heads="16"
ddb.geometry.sectors="63"
ddb.geometry.biosCylinders="1024"
ddb.geometry.biosHeads="255"
ddb.geometry.biosSectors="63"
ddb.uuid.image="88888888-95df-4fde-86ce-ed1390fc6f0a"
ddb.uuid.parent="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.uuid.modification="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.uuid.parentmodification="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
ddb.comment=""
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use different V2V converter. I am using [Starwind V2V](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter), which has more successful conversion ratio as any other previously tested. V2V cannot work directly with OVA files, so you need extract *.vmdk firstly.