# Convert VMDK to VHD

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, vhd, vmdk

I need to convert a VMDK to a VHD for importing into Hyper-V.

It seems that the answers to the apparent duplicate [here](https://superuser.com/questions/483756) do not help me.
The Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter will only take the source as a running VM, I need to convert individual hard drive files.

It seems that I need to download Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter Solution Accelerator (MVMCSA) and use mvdc.exe that comes with this to convert the drive [[2](https://ittechlog.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/)].
But all links to download MVMCSA are broken. I've literally been through dozens of guides that all link to the same microsoft page which gives a 404 like error.
Even the microsoft page itself [[3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967435.aspx)], when you scroll down to the first link which says: "Launch the download of Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter", this also links to the same broken page.

I've tried third party converters such as:

- 5Nine Software’s V2V Easy Converter (this will also only convert a running VM).
- StarWind V2V Converter (has trouble reading the disk and gives: "Not all descriptor fields are present" error).

I'm not sure what to do next. I either need to find another (non-microsoft) download source for MVMCSA or mvdc.exe or use another third party tool that will do what I need.

Comment: I had no trouble using Starwind's program, I have used it before, without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using 2Tware Convert VHD Free 1.0.4 [[1](http://www.2tware.com/product/6/2tware+convert+vhd+free)]

I am still confused as to why I can't download MVMCSA from microsoft, but I suppose that's not relevant now that my problem is solved.